# Removing element from DOM with jquery through plugin Custom Scripts for Customizer

Tags: theme-development, theme-customizer, ssl

This is my first post. I have the plugin powerpress loading an external image from an unsecure source that causes  mixed elements so the page is not fully secured and I get the message "not fully secure". The plugin offers a great shortcode where you can add a default image but is not working with the latest version. This is the image I want to remove from the DOM, hopìng I will get a full secure page.

```
<div class="wp-playlist-current-item">
    <img src="">
<div/>
```

I have followed the theme instructions and installed the plugin  Custom Scripts for Customizer.
I have used this code that removes the image from chrome’s console but not from the live page.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.wp-playlist-current-item img').remove();
});
```

The code is not throwing any errors but is not working. I have tried no conflict Jquery and putting the code in both header and footer.

This is how the code is printed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.wp-playlist-current-item img').remove();});
    /* ]]> */
</script>
```

Hope someone can enlighten my ignorance! Thanks in advance to any such delighful creature...

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code snippet and put it in the `footer.php` file.

```
jQuery( window ).load(function($) {
  $('.wp-playlist-current-item img').remove();
});
```

or

```
jQuery( window ).load(function($) {
  $('.wp-playlist-current-item').find('img').remove();
});
```